# Disable plugin function to use my own

Tags: php

I have copied a function from a plugin because I intend to run the same function with some minor changes.
So, to prevent the plugin function running and also mine, I am trying to disable the plugins function.

Plugin function code

```
/* new product */
function um_activity_new_woo_product( $post_id ) {
....
}
add_action('save_post', 'um_activity_new_woo_product', 99999, 1 );
```

I thought to try the below, but has not stopped the function from running:
`add_filter( 'um_activity_new_woo_product',  '__return_false' );`

Any ideas or changes to try?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `remove_action()` to remove a function from a specified action hook. **[Documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/remove_action/)**

```
remove_action( string $tag, callable $function_to_remove, int $priority = 10 )
```

This function removes a function attached to a specified action hook. This method can be used to remove default functions attached to a specific filter hook and possibly replace them with a substitute.

So in your case,

```
// Remove the function from 'save_post' action
remove_action('save_post', 'um_activity_new_woo_product', 99999 );

// Add your own function my_activity_new_woo_product(), to 'save_post' action
add_action('save_post', 'my_activity_new_woo_product', 99999, 1 );
```

I hope this may help.

Comment: +1, but see this: https://hakre.wordpress.com/2010/08/09/wp-plugins-how-to-remove-a-filter/

Comment: The shared link is about 8 years old. Much have changed since 2010. You may give a try to solution.

Comment: @StephanSamuel let me know if it works.

Comment: Old or not, some of the content of the article is still relevant. Your solution works sometimes. In general, it is correct (hence the +1) but there are cases when it would not work. The OP may be the best person to answer if the solution worked in their case.

Comment: @StephanSamuel sorry for my mistake of wrongly tagging you  instead of  OP.  Based on your 1st comment, I wanted to ask the author of OP to let me know if it worked or not.